# How to draw class diagram and sequence diagram for front-end back-end systems?

Tags: django, frontend, backend, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

I'm going to design a web-based ticket reservation system. It has two parts: 1) back-end which is written with django 2) front-end which is written with vue for web-browsers and with kotlin for mobile applications.

I think Class Diagram is required only for django. But how to draw sequence diagrams for collaborations between front and end? What are other differences between class and sequence diagrams of such systems with stand-alone object oriented systems (e.g., written only in Java)

It would be appreciated if you introduce complete learning resources for this issue.

Thank you